# if statement throwing up errors for no obvious reason? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to build a basic (beginner) project for a BMI calculator that can accept both metric and imperial measurements, I am trying to include `raise` statements to display an error *if* the entered unit of measurement isn't valid like if the user were to enter both imperial and metric or neither. I believe I have used the statements correctly but even if it the unit is entered correctly it still displays the error.

```
import sys

unit = input("To begin, please input your units of measurement (Imperial or Metric) ")

#error if user doesn't enter imperial or metric
if unit.lower().__contains__("metric" or "imperial") == False:
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of 
    measurement is valid/spelled correctly")
    exit(1)

#error if user enters both imperial and metric
if unit.lower().__contains__("metric" and "imperial"):
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of 
    measurement is valid/singular")
    exit(1)
```

I've tried removing them and it works but I want to keep them. I've tried changing the further if statements to elif, to no avail. I have also tried messing around with the statements like changing `if unit.lower().__contains__("metric" or "imperial") == False:` to `if not unit.lower().__contains__("metric" or "imperial")`etc. and again had no success with it. Is there anything that can be done?

Edit: This is only happening when "imperial" is entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing for the existence of True and False in your current code.  An easier way to do it is to just use the `in` keyword, and splitting up the expected terms.

It is much more readable this way as well.

```
import sys

unit = input("To begin, please input your units of measurement (Imperial or Metric) ")

#error if user doesn't enter imperial or metric
if unit.lower() not  in ["metric", "imperial"]:
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of 
    measurement is valid/spelled correctly")
    sys.exit(1)

#error if user enters both imperial and metric
if "metric" in unit.lower() and "imperial" in unit.lower():
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of 
    measurement is valid/singular")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`"metric" or "imperial"` evaluates to `"metric"`, as you can see by pasting it into the REPL:

```
>>> "metric" or "imperial"
'metric'
```

so `unit.lower().__contains__("metric" or "imperial")` is the same as saying `"metric" in unit.lower()`, which will of course be false (and produce your error) if the unit is "imperial":

```
>>> unit = "imperial"
>>> "metric" in unit
False
```

Instead you could use an `or` in between the tests:

```
>>> "metric" in unit or "imperial" in unit
True
```

or put the units into an iterable and use the `any` function:

```
>>> any(u in unit for u in ("metric", "imperial"))
True
```

Comment: And for the second you can use `all(..)` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

`or` does not do what you think it does here. `or` will return the first non `None` or `False` it finds. For example: `False or 12 = None or 12 = 12 or None = 12`. Also you should try to avoid directly calling dunder (double underscored) methods when you can. `__contains__` is used for the `in` function. A better implementiation would therefore be:

```py
import sys

unit = input("To begin, please input your units of measurement (Imperial or Metric) ").lower()

#error if user doesn't enter imperial or metric
if "metric" not in unit and "imperial" not in unit:
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of measurement is valid/spelled correctly")
    exit(1)

#error if user enters both imperial and metric
if "metric" in unit and "imperial" in unit:
    sys.tracebacklimit = 0
    raise Exception("An error has occurred!\n\nPlease check if your unit of measurement is valid/singular")
    exit(1)
```

Edit: the reason that your code only errors when "imperial" is entered is because of the `or` behaviour I described. `"metric" or "imperial"` is evaluated to just `"metric"` so `unit.lower().__contains__("metric" or "imperial") == False` is the same as `unit.lower().__contains__("metric") == False` which is obviously not the behaviour you want.